# Performance implications of OPENJSON in view

Tags: sql-server, view, openjson

Earlier today, I needed to put some small data quickly in a SQL Server database:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[ ... ]') WITH ( colA int, etc. );
```

intending to go back and replace this with a real `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO`, etc. at some point.

SQL Server isn't doing anything smart to cache or store this data, is it? It is parsing the JSON every time the view is queried, right? Just wanted to make sure before I replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just realized I can just do:

```
SELECT * INTO MyNewTable FROM OPENJSON('[ ... ]') WITH ( colA int, etc. );
```

SQL Server is not my first DBMS and I guess I conflated `SELECT INTO` AND `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

I guess it seems kind of weird to not provide this as `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

> SQL Server isn't doing anything smart to cache or store this data, is it?

Correct. A view is just an object to hold the definition of a query. SQL Server doesn't cache the results of queries. (It only caches raw data pages of the tables involved in *most* queries.)

> It is parsing the JSON every time the view is queried, right?

Correct. It has to reprocess your `OPENJSON()` query every time.

> Just wanted to make sure before I replace it.

If you are able to replace it by materializing the results to a table, then querying off of that table will always be computationally easier than reprocessing the statement of your view's query.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, SQL Server needs to parse this every time you access the view.

A much better alternative is to use a `(VALUES` virtual table constructor.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
  (1, 'x'),
  (2, 'y')
) AS v(colA, colB);
```